# PHP Javascript Dynamically indicate clicked menu item

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, menu

I'm currently building a dynamic Website using PHP

I'm having a nav menu like this:

```
<nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="?p=home">Startseite</a></li>
            <li><a href="?p=cars">Fahrzeuge</a></li>
            <li><a href="?p=anfahrt">Anfahrt</a></li>
            <li><a href="?p=impressum">Impressum</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Currently I'm indicating the clicked item by manually adding the css class "current" to that specific item. But, as my website is dynamic, since PHP is including files instead of having the pages manually, I need to indicate it programmatically, how do I go about that? Any Help is greatly appreciated
My CSS:

```
header .highlight, header .current a{
  color:#e8491d;
  font-weight:bold;
}

header a:hover, header li.active{
  color:#cccccc;
  font-weight:bold;
```

Comment: Its simple. If ($_GET['p']=='cars'){ echo "current"; } into class="". You can try it. you write a function or switch or both

Comment: I tried that. But it doesn't work. It isn't indicating anything.

Comment: Nvm. My bad. Works perfectly now. thanks :P

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment of @ivan-barayev:

```
<nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="<?php if( $_GET['p'] == 'home'){echo 'current';} ?>"><a href="?p=home">Startseite</a></li>
            <li class="<?php if( $_GET['p'] == 'cars'){echo 'current';} ?>"><a href="?p=cars">Fahrzeuge</a></li>
            <li class="<?php if( $_GET['p'] == 'anfahrt'){echo 'current';} ?>"><a href="?p=anfahrt">Anfahrt</a></li>
            <li class="<?php if( $_GET['p'] == 'impressum'){echo 'current';} ?>"><a href="?p=impressum">Impressum</a></li>
          </ul>
```

This should work.